# How can I display its own structure in the properties window when creating a custom control (WinForms)

Tags: c#, properties, struct, custom-controls

can someone faced with this problem:
I write custom control. One of its functions should show time.
To solve the problem, I wrote the structure Time:

```
public struct Time
{
    public static implicit operator Time(DateTime date)
    {
        return new Time { Hours = date.Hour, Minutes = date.Minute };
    }

    [Description("Hours")]
    public int Hours { get; set; }

    [Description("Minutes")]
    public int Minutes { get; set; }
}
```

But when you add a control to a form property in the Properties window with the structure of Time - inactive.

It would be desirable to make the user to enter data into the structure as well as in a standard structure, such as Point:

How can I do this? Who faced, please help.

Comment: Hard to guess how you are using this, "add a control to a form property" certainly doesn't make any sense.  Implicit conversions are only ever considered by the C# compiler.  Converting back and forth between a string displayed in the Properties window and the underlying value requires a TypeConverter.  DateTime already has one, it is DateTimeConverter.